# Getting boxes over carousel pervious and next buttons in bootstrap 5, and the buttons are not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to implement a tutorial class project working on bootstrap5 carousel previous and next sliding buttons. if I execute this I'm getting boxes over on the buttons and the buttons are not working. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6mE2.png)

```
<section id="testimonials">

  <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="1000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
        <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
        <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>

      </div>

    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden"></span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: I made a fiddle using your code (https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/3zcs7uxa/1/), and except the heading and image formatting, there's no box over the controls. Maybe something else from your custom styles is overriding the button css. If you make a fiddle with your entire code, we can debug.

Answer (score 0):

You missed add `d-block` `w-100` to `img` selector and I think you did not hook up `bootstrap-5` correctly. I made changes and it works like a charm ;-)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world! Bootstrap 5 Carousel!</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="5000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
        <img class="testimonial-image d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1534972195531-d756b9bfa9f2?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MTF8fGNvZGV8ZW58MHx8MHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="dog-profile">
        <em>Pebbles, New York</em>

      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
        <img class="testimonial-image d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1564865878688-9a244444042a?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8NXx8Y29kZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" alt="lady-profile">
        <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>

      </div>

    </div>
    <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden"></span>
    </button>
    <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" data-bs-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="visually-hidden"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: now the code is running but I still get boxes over on buttons.